# How to show activity indicator before POST/UPDATE call in react-native using redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I need to show an activity indicator in UI while updating call is in process. I am using react-redux to update/post and fetch data

Comment: You can use https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator for example. Not sure what redux has to do with this...

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch an action and Usually there is three part of one action.
 1. Loading.
 2. Success.
 3. Failure.
When you dispatch an action it will triggers the Loading Constant and it will trigger the function where your Network call is being made and you will also return Some data or flag from reducer to your component like "isLoaing: true" and on the basis of the flag we you can display your Activity indicator and when your network call is been processed either it is got the data or error returns that "isLoaing: false" and your Activity indicator will hide on that basis.

```
import { call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { AuthApi } from '../../Services/data/login'
import { FETCH_AUTH_LOADING, FETCH_AUTH_SUCCESS, FETCH_AUTH_FAIL } from'../../Redux/constants/Constants'

function authSuccess (payload) {
   return { type: FETCH_AUTH_SUCCESS, payload }
}

function authFail (payload) {
  return { type: FETCH_AUTH_FAIL, payload }
}

function * authRequest ({requestPayload}) {
  const url = 'Your URL'
  try {
    const resBody = yield call(AuthApi, {url, requestPayload})
    console.log('login api response :::', resBody)
    // let responseData
    if (resBody.ok) {
      yield put(authSuccess({loginData: resBody.data}))
    } else {
      yield put(authFail({ resBody }))
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(authFail({ error }))
  }
}

export default function * authSaga (payload) {
  yield takeEvery(FETCH_AUTH_LOADING, authRequest)
}
```

and your reducer will something like this.

```
const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_AUTH_SUCCESS:
      {
        return {
          ...state,
          isLoading: false,
        }
      } case FETCH_AUTH_LOADING:
      {
        return {
          ...state,
          isLoading: true,
          error: false
        }
      }
    case FETCH_AUTH_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        error: action.payload.error
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```